# Databases in 'Recovery Pending' and 'Backup:CommitLogArchivePoint' not committing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got a bit of an odd one that I'm wondering if anyone's seen before.

Last week I had a bunch of databases showing as 'Recovery Pending'.

Some digging at the time found that SQL was complaining about the trans log being full even though there was a ton of space on the disk and none of the logs were restricted in anyway.

All that the server log shows is 'The Transaction Log for the Database 'XXX' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'

The AG was failed over and things are working fine but I've been doing some digging and can see what happened but don't understand why.

Basically, after a log backup takes it should update the boot page using a transaction named 'Backup:CommitLogArchivePoint'.  Looking at the databases, there is an active transaction 'Backup:CommitLogArchivePoint'.

With a spot more investigation and poking around in the transaction log I can see 'Backup:CommitLogArchivePoint' start but it never committed for the affected databases.  The boot page is updated but the transaction is left uncommitted which obviously means that the transaction log can't be truncated or (for some reason I'm guessing is because SQL thinks that something is changing the boot page) grown out.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before, it happened on a random handful of databases at various points during the day?  I've not seen any occurrences since failing over the AGs.  Any help in understanding what caused this would be great as I'm pulling my hair out here.

Thanks!

Comment: when a database could not be started,sql will log more details in error log,can you please update your question with them

Comment: In this case the databases weren't starting up, they were online and being accessed by the application.  They fell into Recovery Pending after a transaction log backup after which the 'Backup:CommitLogArchivePoint' never committed.  I'll update with entries from the logs....

Comment: Just to clarify, the databases in _Recovery Pending_ status were secondary databases, correct?  Also what patch-level is your SQL 2012 instance at?

Comment: Reasons for The transaction log for database is full due to ACTIVE_TRANSACTION message
1)      There is an active transaction. During a LOG BACKUP there is a long running transaction. This may require another LOG BACKUP.
2)      A deferred transaction. The strict definition is : a transaction is attempting to rollback. During the rollback a resource is unavailable , such as memory or disk. So we need to removed the extra log file. Try this for Recovering DB from Pending state. http://www.xtivia.com/recovering-recovery-pending-status/

Comment: @JohnEisbrener the databases that went into Recovery Pending were the primary databases, the secondaries were Not Synchronising.  We're SP2-CU8.

Comment: @CR241 In my case there is a legitimate active transaction and that's the 'Backup:CommitLogArchivePoint' which never committed.  It's the fact that the transaction never committed and was left open that's the cause of the problems.  The big question is why did that transaction never commit?